# Topoi of algebras vs co-algebras, right adjointness compared to left exactness

Tags: category-theory, duality-theorems, topos-theory

I am asking about topoi of coalgebras over a comonad and algebras over a monad.
The comonad statement I am aware of is as follows:

> Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos. Then if a comonad $T \colon \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ is left exact, then the category of coalgebras $\mathrm{TCoAlg}(\mathcal{E})$ is itself a topos.

While the monad version is:

> Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a topos. Then if a monad $T \colon \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ has a right adjoint, then the category of algebras $\mathrm{TAlg}(\mathcal{E})$ is itself a topos.

Now it seems to me, that the proper dual should be talking about right exactness only for monads instead of having a right adjoint.
So in comonad version, left exact here means $T$ preserves finite limits. In monad version, by having a right adjoint (being a left adjoint) $T$ preserves all colimits.

Can $T$ be weakened to right exact one in the statement for algebras or is there some subtle dualization reason why we suddenly talk about preserving all colimits, not just the finite ones?

Comment: If you dualised everything, you would be asking instead about monads on cotoposes, which is why the statement for monads is different to that for comonads.

Comment: @varkor that indeed seems to be my mistake here